# Why Postgres replication write_lag is measured in seconds

Tags: postgresql, backup, write-ahead-logging

I'm running `pg_receivewal` locally, without compression, it stores segments on the same drive with the db files. Here's the replication statistic:

```sql
imbolc=# select * from pg_stat_replication;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+------------------------------
pid              | 12920                   
usesysid         | 10                           
usename          | postgres                
application_name | pg_receivewal                
client_addr      |               
client_hostname  |                
client_port      | -1             
backend_start    | 2019-08-25 13:18:00.504531+07
backend_xmin     |               
state            | streaming                    
sent_lsn         | C/80009218              
write_lsn        | C/80009218                   
flush_lsn        |                         
replay_lsn       |                              
write_lag        | 00:00:09.838314         
flush_lag        | 00:00:40.028949              
replay_lag       | 00:00:40.028949
sync_priority    | 0              
sync_state       | async
```

If I set `synchronous_commit = off`, `write_lag` still remains significant, above 2.5 seconds.

So my questions are:

- why the `write_lag` is so high?
- does it mean that in case of the db crash last 10 seconds of transactions can be lost?
- is there a way to improve it?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: @jjanes psql (PostgreSQL) 11.5 (Debian 11.5-1+deb10u1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does it mean that in case of the db crash last 10 seconds of transactions can be lost?

If the database has a "soft" crash, like power failure, it will go through autorecovery upon startup, and will recover all transactions (other than those possibly lost to synchronous_commit = off) using the log files it found in the pg_wal or pg_xlog directory.  pg_receivewal is irrelevant to this situation.

If the database has a "hard" crash, such that the storage media is permanently lost and you have to recovery from a backup, then you will lose much more than 10 seconds of transactions.  Since pg_receivewal is storing to the files in the same place as the db files, they will all be lost together.  Running pg_receivewal on the same machine as the database and storing the files to the same drive is a pointless exercise, suitable only for testing purposes.

Other than that issue, you are misinterpreting what the field is for.  It is not to measure the data at risk, it is ["consistent with the goal of measuring synchronous commit and transaction visibility delays for recent write transactions."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html)

Comment: Sure, I use the same drive here only for the sake of finding minimal possible lag. But it's actually the same if I use a network drive. What is more suitable for measuring data at risk?

Comment: I don't think there really is a good way of measuring data at risk like that. Instead the database provides for making guarantees (synchronous_standby_names), rather than measuring the size of the non-guarantee.